# Mongoose findOne Returns Null Object Value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have saved some documents in mongodb compass successfully. I am trying to retrieve the values by querying some of the parameters.

I understand that mongodb findOne has arguments such as 
`query, fields(by default value: all), options and callback`
 but the result of the operation returns null and throws a type error.

Here's my code:

```
router.get('/edit-page/:slug',(req,res) => {
  console.log('slug:\t' + req.params.slug);
  Pages.findOne({slug: req.params.slug},(errs, page) => {
    if(errs){
      req.flash('danger', 'page not found');
      console.error(errs);
    } else {
      console.log(page);
      res.render('admin/edit_page',{
        title: page.title,
        slug: slug,
        content: page.content,
        id: page._id
      });
    }
  });
});
```

copy of my data structure in mongo compass:

```
{   
  "_id":"5a9568fa5ce418423ca8e29f",
  "title":"Home",
  "slug":"home",
  "content":"Home Page for Node CMS Cart",
  "sorting":100,
  "__v":0
}
```

Error Thrown:

```
GET /admin/routes 200 8.634 ms - 3064
slug:    about-us
null
events.js:183
     throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
     ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of null
    at Pages.findOne (E:\nodeCMSApp\routes\admin_routes.js:98:29)
    at model.Query.<anonymous> 
(E:\nodeCMSApp\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:3928:16)
    at E:\nodeCMSApp\node_modules\kareem\index.js:297:21
    at E:\nodeCMSApp\node_modules\kareem\index.js:135:16
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I dont seem to understand why in my callback, I can't get a reference to `page.title` as the default fields when not specified is all fields.

PS: Pages is my model class.

How do I work around this problem, if it is?
Thanks.

Comment: can you add URL also which you are calling.

Comment: can u tell add what these statements are printed console.log('slug:\t' + req.params.slug); console.log(page);

Comment: @Pavan, the slug is printed correctly as it's coming from the req body. However, page value is null

Comment: @RahulSharma, this is the complete url http://localhost:4003/admin/routes/edit-page/%20about-us. I don't know why %20 is attached but that doesn't seem to be the problem

Comment: the code looks fine only you have to handle the condition.

Comment: I feel %20about-us is problem - %20 is http encoding char for space. i think this might be problem - documents are searched with this ' about-s' instead of 'about-us' so there isn't one document matching so you are getting page as null.

Comment: That could be right. But in my code to create pages, I have not attached any spaces. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is fine, You need to handle the condition.

```
router.get('/edit-page/:slug', (req, res) => {
    console.log('slug:\t' + req.params.slug);
    Pages.findOne({
        slug: req.params.slug
    }, (errs, page) => {
        if (errs) {
            req.flash('danger', 'page not found');
            console.error(errs);
        } else {
            console.log(page);
            if (page) {
                res.render('admin/edit_page', {
                    title: page.title,
                    slug: slug,
                    content: page.content,
                    id: page._id
                });
            } else {
                res.status(400).send('Error message');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You were right about the condition. It prints 'error message' but how to solve it?

Comment: This is the solution because you can't control user inputs. if slug data is available in the database, it'll work. but you need to handle negative scenarios otherwise server code will break. Instead of the message, you can redirect to error page also.

Comment: Slug data is available in db but why is the code breaking?

Comment: are you passing the same slug, ignore case also if you want. then try

Answer (score 1):

```
  router.get('/edit-page/:slug', (req, res) => {
      Page.findOne({slug : req.params.slug}).then((page) => {
        if(!page) { //if page not exist in db
          return res.status(404).send('Page not found');
        }
        res.render('admin/edit_page', { //page  exist
          title: page.title,
          slug: page.slug,
          content: page.content,
          id: page._id
        });
      }).catch((e) => {//bad request 
        res.status(400).send(e);
      });
    });
```

Use this code it will work the logic is same but i have handled the conditions using promises it definitely worked for me. Hope it helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

@Rahul Sharma's code is okay, but the slug data from DB wasn't parsed correctly.

```
           res.render('admin/edit_page', {
                title: page.title,
                slug: page.slug,
                content: page.content,
                id: page._id
            });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).